# Alternatives to TIOCSTI now that is disable on default for kernels >= 6.2

Tags: c, linux

I find myself in the need to re-implement a function that used ioctl and the TIOCSTI to fill the terminal input.

```
void fill_terminal_input(char *cmd, bool padding)
{
    if (cmd && strlen(cmd)>0) {
        size_t size = strlen(cmd);
        unsigned i;
        char *c;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
             // terminal I/O control, simulate terminal input
             c = (cmd + i);
             ioctl(0, TIOCSTI, c);
        }
        if (padding) printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I found [this](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Examples#with-write-to-terminal-capabilities) workaround by using pipe redirection of the output but it fell jacking at best. It also dependent from the shell used so it does not relay suit my use case

Comment: You need to refactor so you do buffering in the application. Then your buffering functions can provide a way to insert into the buffer.

Comment: The default kernel configuration has `CONFIG_LEGACY_TIOCSTI=y` which allows the `TIOCSTI` ioctl command by default, but of course a distro could have unset `CONFIG_LEGACY_TIOCSTI` for the kernel binaries they ship, which would disallow that ioctl command by default. Regardless, there is a run-time `sysctl` parameter `dev.tty.legacy_tiocsti` that controls whether that ioctl command is allowed.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for pseudoterminals?

Comment: @Barmar and what would be the system call i need to use then? So i can go read the documentation ecc ecc because i did not find any alternative.

Comment: There is no system call for this. This is code you have to write in your application, to replace the system function that has been removed for security reasons.

Comment: With your [attempted] use of `TIOCSTI`, we know you're trying to inject input into the _same_ app. So, this [probably] means, that _you_ control the recipient code, such as: `read(0,buf,1);` The TL;DR is to either do your own buffering or use `fgetc(stdin);` instead of the `read`. Then, you can use `ungetc(c,stdin)`.